# Azure Data Factory V2 - Process One Array Field on Row as a string

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I created an Azure Data Factory pipeline that uses a Rest data source to pull data from a Rest API and copy it to an Azure SQL database.  Each row in the Rest data source contains approx. 8 fields but one of those fields contains an array of values.  I'm using a Copy Data task.  How do I get all values from that field to map into 1 of my database fields, possibly as a string?  I've tried clicking on "Collection Reference" for that field but if the array field has 5 values, it creates 5 different records in my SQL table for the one source row. If I don't select "Collection Reference", it only grabs the first value in the array.
I looked into using the Data Flow mapping task instead, but that one doesn't seem to support a Rest API dataset as a data source.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the output of REST API as a JSON file in Azure blob storage by Copy Data activity. Then you can use that file as Source and do transformation in Data Flow.  Also you can use Lookup activity to get the JSON data and invoke the SP to store the data in Azure SQL Database(This way will be cheaper and it's performance will be better).